# Чтение данных из Excel с дополнительными условиями

Tags: c#, excel

Есть вот такой лист в Excel:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент застрял на этапе извлечения данных, потому что имеются специфические требования, как:

1. Ячейки, объединённые Оранжевым, должны храниться в виде Год + Последний день квартала, т.е. 2015 + Q1 = 2015_03_31 и быть ключем в HashMap01.
2. Синяя ячейка должна быть значением в HashMap01 (обведено зелёным)
3. В то же время, HashMap'a01, обведённая зелёным, должна быть Value в другой HashMap02'е, ключем в которой должно быть значение с ячейки, обведённой красным =)

В итоге, должна получится такая структура из двух HashMap:

```
Key = "Stato Patrimoniale", Value = new HashMap (Key = 2015_03-31, Value = 253 426 400),
                            Value = new HashMap (Key = 2015_06-30, Value = 247 512 913),
                            Value = new HashMap (Key = 2015_09-30, Value = 249 425 209)
```

и так до конца текущего ряда. После прохода в конец, спускаемся на один ряд ниже и продолжаем в том же духе.

Так вот: как это всё написать на C#? Я пробовал через OleDB, но ничего не вышло. Не могу понять, как вытащить всё в нужном порядке.

Comment: Не проще ли обработать документ в vba и сохранить результат обработки в C#
Документ спокойно читается любым продуктом , созданным в VS , контора то одна !!!

Comment: Даже не знаю... В VB я совсем профан, не знаю ничего.